# Book example Profit maximization understanding

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

This may not be the right place to ask this kind of question and it also sound a bit stupid, but please help me understand better. I am not able to to see why on page 192 "which imposes another constrain x2 +3 x3<= 600" come up? With the fact that Nuit and Luxe require the same packing machinery. Please take sometimes to read the book, (I understand it sounds like I am too lazy to post the more completed question, it does require reader to understand a bit more than usual question to help).
Here is the link to the [book](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf)

Comment: Please add some necessary information so that one can understand your question without reading the book.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is helpful, but I think that the quote is simply introducing an additional constraint to the extension of the two-dimensional problem (two unknowns) presented on p.189 to a three-dimensional problem (three unknowns) introduced at the bottom of p.192.

The offered interpretation of the additional constraint is that it reflects a constraint of the 'packaging machine', namely the machine can package at most 600 items (inclusive). Also, the quote informs the reader that for every package related to 'Nuit' ($x_2$) the machine can process three times as much 'Luxe' ($3x_3$).

I don't think there's anything more to it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would help if this answer (and the question, of course) gave some more information about what the book actually says. At the moment, neither the question nor your answer makes any sense at all to somebody who doesn't have the book open at the relevant page.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'd vote for close if I could; the Q is about a linear programming maximization problem; the relevant section describes the constraints using a narrative of a pastry shop profit maximization problem related to the production of different varieties of chocolates;

Comment: @user42582 Thank you.  It's helpful. With your help, I can now interpret "x2 +3 x3<= 600" as the additional constraint with confidence.  Where did you find that 600 in the first place? Yes I understand that "Nuit' (x2) the machine can process three times as much 'Luxe' (3x3)". Appreciate any hint.

Comment: @Maxfield I have not read the entire book so I cannot positively say that the *rhs* of the inequality constraint you are interested in is not derived at some earlier stage of the development of the book's argumentation strategy; from the short passages I read I would assume that the writer simply asserts that '$600$' is the 'appropriate' constraint to use in the context of the example; with the caveat stated above, I'd suggest you simply accept the inequality constraint '*as is*'.